# Safe ways to abseil last

Tags: safety, climbing, mountaineering, rappelling

When being the last one to abseil you obviously need to make sure that when you are down, you can retrieve the rope. While the most common way is probably to use twin/half ropes and to put one rope through the anchor and join it with the other, there are numerous other possibilities.

What methods to set up a safe abseil where you can retrieve the rope exist?
When are they usually applied (e.g. for a specific kind of abseil anchor)?
How is the setup done and what material is used?

Comment: Hmm... I think for "safe" the only way is to have enough cordage for twice your total descent.  At least half of that cordage must be strong enough to rap on and thick enough to work with your chosen rappel device.  (All the ways I know to bypass this fall in the "hideously dangerous" category.)

Comment: @requiem Well I at least know of the option of using a thin cord just as long as your single rope which looses the knot on top when pulling on it. I never did it myself and I dont know the exact setup (nor why it should be used), but it might be save I think. I just assume there are some techniques like this out there.